# How to create Entity Framework in Visual Studio for Windows Forms (.NET framework)

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8, windowsformshost

I have installed Visual Studio 2022 and created a "Windows Forms App (.NET framework)" project (target is .NET framework 4.8).

Then I installed Entity Framework v6.4.4 and `Microsoft.SqlServer- 1.0.0` from NuGet Package Manager. Then I picked 'Add.Net Entity Data Model' through 'EF Designer from database' successfully. The problem comes when I build the solution for DataSource. Hence I am not able to add DataSource.

I tried the same thing on my old machine which has Visual Studio 2019. My .NET framework is 4.7.2.

Packages are `EntityFramework-6.2.0` and `Microsoft.SqlServer-1.0.0`. I followed the same steps and my project is working completely fine. I have successfully added DBEntities. I believe Visual Studio 2022 doesn't support these packages. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Define "The problem", what errors are you getting?